# Android Studio Error: Cannot resolve symbol ' MapFragment'

Tags: android-studio

I am taking an Udacity course on Google Maps and have started building an app acc. to instructions. I am getting the above mentioned error in an xml file, yet the external libraries of the app contain the class that AS cannot resolve.(see screenshot)

[image]

What step do I need to take to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, quite obviously the class should have started with a capital like in the library!! ... but shouldn't the class name be written in lower case in the android namespace?